# Android, wait for activity to finish in asynctask

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I have a AsyncTask in which an activity is launched during the doInBackground method:

```
private class startupTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(StartupActivity.this, LoginConnectorActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("account", account);
        startActivity(intent);
        return null;
    }
}
```

I want to wait for the called activity to finish before letting the AsyncTask finish. What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what you are asking beats the purpose of the `AsyncTask`, as `AsyncTask` suppose to run asynchronously with other tasks of the app and finish in the background. So if you want to wait while this task finishes then don't make it a `AsyncTask`, as simple as that.

Comment: It seems like you want to use `startActivityForResult()` instead.

Answer (score 3):

The question really is *why would you ever do this?*

The purpose of the `AsyncTask` is to provide an easy means of performing a potentially expensive task so that it does not block the UI thread. From your question, it sounds like you could easily achieve your task without the use of multi-threading.

What you really want is to launch your `Activity` with `startActivityWithResult()`. Then start the new activity when the launched activity returns control to `onActivityResult()`.